# Cant't get uniques, estimatedMinutesWatched, averageViewDuration, averageViewPercentage - Youtube Analytics Api

Tags: youtube, analytics

I'm using the Youtube Analytics Api, and everything works fine, but when I try to get results for these parameters - uniques, estimatedMinutesWatched, averageViewDuration, averageViewPercentage - I get this error from Google:

*'The query is not supported'*.

I read the documentation, and everything is set fine (the authentication is ok, the dimensions and metrics is fine too, and other querys works well), but still no luck..

If anyone had this problem, and know how to resolve, please tell,

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not combine uniques with the watchtime metrics.

Checkout the documentation that list the supported queries:
https://developers.google.com/youtube/analytics/v1/available_reports
You can only combine uniques with the metrics in the same table cell.